# How to detect mouse click and keypress?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I want to find mouse click and key press is occur or not between start time and end time (starttime:9:30 and endtime:10:30) using Python script.

Python code is here:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
 
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print("Mouse clicked.")

def on_press(key):
    print("key is pressed")

with Listener(on_click=on_click,on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

with this I am able to get the mouse click and key press, but I don't have idea for time-interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your code didn't work for me.
I had to make some changes in order to test it.
The problem in my case were the events mouse and keyboard at the same time.

Here I post my changed code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput.mouse import Listener


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print("Mouse clicked.")

def on_press(key):
    print("key is pressed")



from pynput import keyboard
key_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
key_listener.start()

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

(Source: [Using Mouse and Keyboard Listeners Together in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973453/using-mouse-and-keyboard-listeners-together-in-python))

If you want to count seconds, minutes and so on, you can use **time** like @Ujjwal Dash said.

The Mouse events will be noticed if its between 1 and 10 seconds since the script was started.

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput.mouse import Listener


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    delta_time = (int(time.time()-start_time))
    if delta_time >=1 and delta_time <=10:
        if pressed:
            print("Mouse clicked.")

def on_press(key):
    delta_time = (int(time.time()-start_time))
    print(delta_time)
    print("key is pressed")

start_time = time.time()

from pynput import keyboard
key_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
key_listener.start()

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

**delta_time** ... time in seconds since script start

If you want it to listen to a specific time of the day, you can work with the unix time and convert it with the time module.
In this code the mouse will be noticed if it's between 7:00 and 10:00 localtime hours.

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def check_time():
    t = time.localtime(time.time())
    if t.tm_hour<= 10 and t.tm_hour>=7:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if check_time():
        if pressed:
            print("Mouse clicked.")
    else:
        pass

def on_press(key):
    print("key is pressed")

from pynput import keyboard
key_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
key_listener.start()

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about it, but I think you could do use the function `time` from the module `time`. You can bind `start = time.time()` to your start button and `end = time.time()` to your end button. Then, for each interval use `i = end - start`.